# ¿Cómo se debe pronunciar en español el topónimo "Liechtenstein" y su gentilicio "liechtensteiniano"?

Tags: pronunciación, gentilicio, topónimos

*Liechtenstein* es un topónimo que me llama la atención. Al contrario que en otros nombres de país como Francia, Alemania, Inglaterra, que están adaptados, en este caso su versión española es idéntica a la original (*[Fürstentum Liechtenstein](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liechtenstein)*, Principado de Liechtenstein).

Dada la complejidad de la palabra y mi profundo desconocimiento del alemán, yo siempre la había pronunciado algo así como `/liechenstein/` cuando la veía escrita... hasta que vi la película *[Destino de caballero](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0183790/?ref_=nv_sr_1)* y me di cuenta de que el título ficticio del prota era "sir Ulrich von Liechtenstein", que precisamente hace mención a este país, y lo pronuncian como `/lijtenstain/`.

Así pues, dado que el nombre del país en español coincide con el original alemán, pues pensaba que lo mejor era precisamente pronunciarlo como oí en la película, y así lo vengo haciendo... hasta que me doy cuenta de que el gentilicio del país está en el DLE escrito en letras redondas, como palabra ya adaptada:

> **[liechtensteiniano, na](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NHVpY7E)**
>
> 1. adj. Natural de Liechtenstein, país de Europa. U. t. c. s.

¿Eso quiere decir que entonces el nombre del país debe pronunciarse en español como `/liechtenstein/`? ¿Igual que su gentilicio se pronuncia `/liechtensteiniano/` y no `/lijtenstainiano/`? ¿Existen otras palabras en español que tengan una sílaba acaba en *ch*?

Comment: Yo siempre he pensado que los países y lugares se deberían llamar como sus habitantes se refieren a ellos mismos. Entiendo que la historia hace que p. ej. le digamos Holanda a Netherlands pero si uno revisa bien eso es un error. Si ellos lo llaman `/lijtenstain/` así lo deberíamos llamar los demás.

Comment: Los holandeses se refieren a su propio país como ***Koninkrijk der Nederlanden*** lit. *Reino de los países bajos* Netherlands es un anglicismo que les niega el orgullo monárquico que sienten por su bienamada reina (un neerlandés dixit)

Comment: Caramba todos los días se aprende algo. Siempre jure que topónimo y gentilicio serían sinónimos, hoy aprendí que no es el caso, mil disculpas, retiro mi respuesta *Non sequitur* y si alguien es tan amable de pasarme mi ropa, procederé a vestirme y regresar por donde llegue... Saludos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo tiendo a pronunciar el país palabra como si fuese *lijtenstáin* y por consiguiente a su gentilicio como *lijtenstainiano*.  No sé por qué nunca se adoptó una forma autóctona en español, pero fácilmente podría ser porque el nombre del país viene del nombre de una familia.  Parece que en los idiomas europeos la mayoría pronuncian el nombre tal como en alemán de acuerdo con su fonética, especialmente dado que casi ningún idioma modifica la ortografía aparte de quizás algún tilde.  Así, por ejemplo, el sonido [ç] nos da [s] en portugués (/liʃtẽnsˈtain(ɨ)/), pero [k] en inglés (/ˈlɪktənstaɪn/) y [x] en ruso (Лихтенште́йн o /lʲixtʲnʂtejn/).

Las palabras con *ch* al final de una sílaba interna son poquísimas:

- pechblenda
- [pchs](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SEsGpyh) <sub>(eh.... no sé si está al final o qué jaja)</sub>
- brechtiano
- liechtensteiniano
- [totomochtle](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=totomochtle)

Más hay que terminan en *ch*:

- capararoch
- catch
- coach
- crómlech
- crónlech
- gulasch
- kirsch
- kitsch
- lunch
- mach
- maquech
- pech
- poch
- sándwich
- sketch
- zarévich

Como se nota, la pronunciación de estas palabras pueden variar. Pueden pronunciarse tal como una *ch* típica como en *sandwich* o *zarévich*).   Puede salir como una *c* como en el caso de *pechblenda* que admite forma alternativa *pecblenda*.  En otros casos, la *ch* puede salir como la *j* (*mach*), y otros como la *ll* rioplatense (como es *kircsh* o *gulasch* que también admite la grafía *gulash*).  En gran parte eso se debe a la pronunciación que tiene el dígrafo (o trígrafo según la palabra) en el idioma del cual el castellano importó la palabra.

Comment: La de "pchs" podría ser la respuesta a "¿cuál es la palabra más larga registrada por el DLE que solo tiene consonantes?" :-D

Comment: @Charlie, no solo la más larga sino de las pocas palabras sin consonantes que hay

Comment: pchs más que una palabra es la onomatopeya de "me importa un rábano" jajajaja

Comment: También hay las palabras que acaban con *-ch* (i.e. la sílaba terminal): *mach, huich, lunch, kirsch, kitch, crómlech, sándwich, zarevich, capararoch*

Comment: @ukemi se me olvidó buscar como sílaba final

Comment: (También también hay *[bacilo de]* [*Koch*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8QpXnCs) y [*ch*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8QpXnCs) sí mismo)

Comment: @ukemi no puse Koch porque es un poco tramposo, por ser nombre propio (y así podríamos recoger muchas más como Marrakech o Folch entre otros apellidos catalanes)

Comment: Pero vamos, razón tienes ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Solo para confirmar la estupenda [respuesta de guifa](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/25903/12637): en octubre de 2014 la RAE publicaba un tuit respondiendo a otra persona que preguntaba lo mismo (la pronunciación correcta del topónimo *Liechtenstein*), que decía:

> La tendencia actual es reproducir en lo posible la pronunciación original.

Aprovechando esta respuesta pregunté si entonces el gentilicio debía reproducir también esta pronunciación original. La respuesta ha sido:

> A los derivados les corresponde con frecuencia una pronunciación mixta, que combina la de la lengua de origen (o una aproximación a ella) en la parte del nombre propio extranjero al que se asocian y la española en el sufijo derivativo.

Así pues, con este tuit entiendo que, efectivamente, las pronunciaciones `/lijtenstain/` y por tanto `/lijtenstainiano/` (como pronunciación mixta) son la tendencia actual, tal y como recoge y atestigua la RAE.

Por cierto, que nunca aprenderé a preguntar si algo es "la tendencia actual" en vez de si "debe ser así" o si "es lo correcto"...

Comment: If you are going to keep the German pronunciation why not call the people Liechtensteiner?